# Tensorflow DLL import failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using python 3.6.1, I've installed tensorflow-gpu via pip.

Whenever I execute my script it bonks out on the first tensorflow import statement with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Tools\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Tools\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've followed tensorflow-gpu setup by the book (i.e. following the steps in the official tensorflow documentaion to the letter). Has anyone had problems with this before?

EDIT:

I've also tried installing tensorflow cpu via pip, but then I get a different error message:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

My computers specs:

i7 4500K @ 5GHz
NVidea 1070
Samsung SSD
32GB DDR4 RAM

Comment: Try to add the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH%.

Comment: Is that because I've installed tensorflow-gpu rather than bog standard tensorflow? I tried bog standard tensorflow cpu, but I then get a different error message. I'm going to update my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's only relevant if you install tensorflow-gpu. You can find more suggestions concering your problem [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033).